# Is there any way to delete all dspace items without deleting the collections and communities structure?

Tags: dspace

**Dspace 5.10v**

Is there any way to delete all dspace items without deleting the collections and communities structure?

I have a base of 1.5 million records and I need to clean this data without erasing the collection structure which is quite extensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Batch Metadata Editing.config/modules/bulkedit.cfg must have "allowexpunge = true"

- Export each community csv using the administrator option "Export Metadata"
- Delete from this csv all columns except "id" and "column".
- Add one last column named "action" with the value "expunge"
- Import this csv using command line "[dspace]/bin/dspace metadata-import -f new_file.csv -e admin@user.com"

More info: [https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC5x/Batch+Metadata+Editing#BatchMetadataEditing-Performing'actions'onitems](https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC5x/Batch+Metadata+Editing#BatchMetadataEditing-Performing%27actions%27onitems)

Comment: but would that be a single file? or would i have to do for each collection?

Comment: One for each Community